# why do not show alias name in iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I create a website by Visual Studio and publish it.
Then in IIS I do:
dd application and
set alias name to CIP and set physical path.
Home page is loaded correctly but other pages have wrong URLs in addressbar.
This is homepage URL: "`http://localhost/CIP/Pages/Default.aspx`".
When I click on the other link showed below link without CIP(alias name).
"`http://localhost/Pages/OperationPersonelProgram.aspx`".

Comment: Does that second page (without the `CIP`) actually load, or do you get an error? If it's the second, it's likely to be a fault with how your website is generating URLs.

Comment: no problem when run website in Visual Studio, but in iis show this error: Server Error in '/' Application

Comment: Then, as I indicated, it's a problem with how *your* site is generating URLs. But since you've not shown us any code, you can't expect us to help to diagnose the issue further.

Comment: <a class="link" href="/Pages/HostessPersonalProgram.aspx">mylink</a>, i want show this link with alias name in iis

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your application make sure that the URLs it's using make sense. This requires *some* server side code to execute. So, if you're writing an MVC website you would use the [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class, something like:

```
<a class="link" href="@Url.Content("~/Pages/HostessPersonalProgram.aspx")">mylink</a>
```

(The above is Razor syntax, but similar should be possible).

Most of the different "styles" of ASP.Net offer a similar shorthand for obtaining the correct URL, but if all else fails you can always use [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var url = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Pages/HostessPersonalProgram.aspx");
```